# Reading thread dump to debug an exhausted database connection pool

Tags: java, mysql, connection-pooling

I have a web app being served by jetty + mysql. I'm running into an issue where my database connection pool gets exhausted, and all threads start blocking waiting for a connection. I've tried two database connection pool libraries: (1) bonecp (2) hikari. Both exhibit the same behavior with my app.

I've done several thread dumps when I see this state, and all the blocked threads are in this state (not picking on bonecp, I'm sure it's something on my end now):

```
"qtp1218743501-131" prio=10 tid=0x00007fb858295800 nid=0x669b waiting on condition [0x00007fb8cd5d3000]
  java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000763f42d20> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2082)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.DefaultConnectionStrategy.getConnectionInternal(DefaultConnectionStrategy.java:82)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.AbstractConnectionStrategy.getConnection(AbstractConnectionStrategy.java:90)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.getConnection(BoneCP.java:553)
    at com.me.Foo.start(Foo.java:30)
    ...
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. I was thinking that I would see some stack traces in the thread dump where my code was stuck doing some lengthly operation, not waiting for a connection. For example, if my code looks like this:

```
public class Foo {
    public void start() {
        Connection conn = threadPool.getConnection();
        work(conn);
        conn.close();
    }

    public void work(Connection conn) {
        .. something lengthy like scan every row in the database etc ..
    }
}
```

I would expect one of the threads above to have a stack trace that shows it working away in the work() method:

```
...
at com.me.mycode.Foo.work()
at com.me.mycode.Foo.start()
```

but instead they're just all waiting for a connection:

```
...
at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.getConnection() // ?
at com.me.mycode.Foo.work()
at com.me.mycode.Foo.start()
```

Any thoughts on how to continue debugging would be great.

Some other background: the app operates normally for about 45 minutes, mem and thread dumps show nothing out of the ordinary. Then the condition is triggered and the thread count spikes up. I started thinking it might be some combination of sql statements the app is trying to perform which turn into some sort of lock on the mysql side, but again I would expect some of the threads in the stack traces above to show me that they're in that part of the code.

The thread dumps were taken using visualvm.

Thanks

Comment: did you ever try your connection logic with a "try with resources"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take advantage of the configuration options for the connection pool (see [BoneCPConfig](http://jolbox.com/bonecp/downloads/site/apidocs/com/jolbox/bonecp/BoneCPConfig.html) / [HikariCPConfig](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby)). First of all, set a connection time-out (HikariCP `connectionTimeout`) and a leak detection time-out (HikariCP `leakDetectionThreshold`, I could not find the counterpart in BoneCP). There might be more configuration options that dump stack-traces when something is not quite right.

My guess is that your application does not always return a connection to the pool and after 45 minutes has no connection in the pool anymore (and thus blocks forever trying to get a connection from the pool). Treat a connection like opening/closing a file, i.e. always use try/finally:

```
public void start() {

    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        work(conn = dbPool.getConnection());
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, both connection pools have options to allow `JMX monitoring`. You can use this to monitor for strange behavior in the pool.

Comment: Yes I enabled logging for bonecp and it pointed out my connection leak to me :D

Answer (score -1):

I question the whole design.

If you have a waiting block in a multithreaded netIO, you need a better implementation of the connection.

I suggest you take a look at non blocking IO (Java.nio, channels package), or granulate your locks.